# How to create landscape mode only for specific dashboard in react native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I have an app in react native. this app has 2 different dashboards. the dashboard depends on the user who logged in.

My question is if there is an option to require that one of the dashboard will always be in landscape mode which the other one could be both?

Thank you for the help

**Solution:**

You should use with this
[link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-orientation)

Follow after the configuration on the bottom and you can see how to use this feature.

Comment: you can use this library https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation

Comment: except those configurations in documentation you don't need to do anything else

Comment: @Nima thank you it works!